# Rails 5 API - Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I refactored one of my controllers to move the update logic into a service

so the controller looks like this

```
  #user_controller.rb
  def update
    UserManagement::UserUpdatePassword.new(@user, user_params).call
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def get_user
    @user ||= User.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id])
  end
```

So as I said before I moved the entire logic into a service that takes care of the update logic and the redirects. I know there might be a debate in leaving the redirects in the controller.

```
#user management service
module UserManagement
 class UserUpdatePassword
  attr_reader :user, :params

  def initialize(get_user, user_params)
    @user = get_user
    @params = user_params
  end

  def call
    if user.password_reset_token < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password reset has expired."
    elsif user.update_attributes(params)
      redirect_to confirmation_password_resets_path, :notice => "Congratulations! Your Password has been reset."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
 end
end
```

If I use the Awesome Print in the call method I can the user and params properly being passed but I'm getting a

`NoMethodError (undefined method "build_notice" for nil:NilClass):`

and I can't figure out why

Comment: Does the `build_notice` method exist in your app?

Comment: You can't call "redirect_to" and "render" inside UserUpdatePassword, and I'm not talking about design here, as far as I know you simply can't because these methods belong to the application controller and shouldn't be accessible inside UserUpdatePassword. Please extract those calls to the controller and let us know the outcome.

Comment: It would help if there was enough code to reproduce the issue. Also where in `call` is the failure. One change I might make, if you want to access controller methods like `render` then it is probably better to pass the controller into your `Manager` class.

Comment: It has to do with calling redirect_to or render in the service. I though about using something like `UserManagement::UserUpdatePassword.new(@user, self).call` but I don't know if it would work and I don't think it's elegant. There is also the idea of using `callback` but seems to defeat the purpose too. I'll refactor and post the whole solution here. thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it caused by [airbrake](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake) gem. You should add environment condition to airbrake (or errbit) initializer.

*config/initializers/airbrake.rb*

```rb
if Rails.env.production?
  Airbrake.configure do |config|
    # your configuration here
  end
end
```

and add `gem airbrake` to the `production` group.

*Gemfile*

```rb
group :production do
  gem 'airbrake'
end
```